# Java Round Trip Safe Byte Array to String Conversion

Tags: java, arrays, encoding, data-conversion

I cannot seem to find an appropriate API to do roundtrip safe conversion

```
(new String(new byte[]{-84}, "UTF-8")).getBytes("UTF-8")[0]
```

produces -17, instead of -84

Comment: There is no such thing. You MUST NOT use `String` to store binary data, plain and simple. Or use something like Base64.

Comment: How to do Base64 then?

Answer (score -1):

Base64.getDecoder().decode(Base64.getEncoder().encode(new byte[]{-84}))